# Fails to read/write a plist file in the Preferences folder of a group container

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, appstore-sandbox

My sandboxed application and its helper were using NSUserDefaults to manage their preferences. The preferences file was located in the group container shared by the two applications. I’ve decided to use a plist file instead.

```
groupContainerURL = [fm containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier:SC_AppGroupName];
prefsURL = [groupContainerURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:SC_PrefsRelativePath];

if(! [fm fileExistsAtPath:prefsURL.path])
    [self createDictionary];
else
{   prefsFile = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfURL:prefsURL];
    if(prefsFile == nil)
        [self fileManagerAlert];    // a NSAlert
}
```

When I want to read or write the file in the group container, access is denied. prefsFile is set to nil when I create it from the URL. The following messages appear in the console :

```
25/07/2016 17:18:02,650 sandboxd[126]: ([1445]) MyApp(1445) deny file-read-data /Users/lionel/Library/Group Containers/X2RD457A99.com.myCompany.myApp/Library/Preferences/X2RD457A99.com.myCompany/MyApp.plist
25/07/2016 17:02:02,235 sandboxd[126]: ([1413]) MyApp(1413) deny file-write-create /Users/lionel/Library/Group Containers/X2RD457A99.com.MyCompany.MyApp/Library/Preferences/X2RD457A99.com.MyCompany.MyApp.plist
```

However, I can access for exemple the Caches folder of the group container without any problem. I dont think that I’ve missed an entitlement key. Is the use of the Preferences folder reserved to NSUserDefaults ?

Comment: I answer myself. I've stored the dictionary in another folder of the group container than the Preferences folder and now I can freely read or write the file. It seems that the Preferences folder located in the group container can only be accessed by NSUserDefaults.